# Sync clock of 2 devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, network-programming, synchronization, core-bluetooth

I"m working on a realtime multiplayer game where 2 players can battle against each other. Players connect their devices via bluetooth.Device A connects to Device B (or vice versa). The game has a count down clock. I'm struggling to sync the count down clock so that both players start playing the game at the same time. This is due to the bluetooth latency. This latency differs from just a couple of milliseconds to 1-2 seconds sometimes.

what approach should I take to solve this?

right now I have the following process:

```
- player A and player B are connected through bluetooth
- Player A goes into "ready" state by pressing the ready button.
- message gets send to player B informing that player A is ready
- Player B goes into "ready" state by pressing the ready button. 
- message gets send to player A informing that player B is ready.**
- when both players ready, the count down begins.
```

** because there is a slight delay for the "ready" message to arrive to player A, the countdown of player B has already started, since it only has to update a local state variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both device clocks are synchronized against the same network source, you could just have them agree on an explicit time in the future for the countdown to end instead of trying to do "x seconds relative to now". Most devices are automatically synchronized with the same network time.

Comment: Well, it's not that both devices are linked to a single source. It's one device that is connected to the other.

Comment: `Settings -> General -> Date & Time -> Set Automatically` links them to a single time baseline source. Once they are linked to each other, they can both agree on an "end time", then clock it locally.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I'm not completely following on the part "agree on end time". Could you perhaps explain the process in steps like I did in my original post?

Comment: In your step 5 send a timestamp from B to A for when the countdown ends. The "[NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970" timestamp should normally already be in sync between the two devices. BTW, you should also handle the case when A and B press at the same time...

Comment: so I've checked the timeIntervalSince1970 between the 2 devices and they are not synced. there is a difference of about 1 second between the 2 devices. Date&Time is set automatically.